# Что означает "Теневой стэк" или "Теневое хранилище" (Stack’s shadow store) в "соглашении вызовов для x64" в Windows API?

Tags: windows, ассемблер, стек, x86-64

Я читал [соглашение Microsoft-ское](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170) о том как вызывать функции из Windows API когда пишешь программу на ассемблере 64-битную, но тут заметил что говорят про какой то «Теневой стэк» или «Теневое пространство». Не понимаю что это, зачем, и как это сделать.
Ну то есть я догадываюсь что это возможно просто зарезервированное в место в стэке, но если так, то зачем и сколько мéста резервировать - не понятно. И ещё, в таком случае, не понятно нужно ли **резервировать каждый раз** перед вызовом функции или **только один раз** в программе.
В этой документации Microsoft не нашел точно что это. Где-то говорят про 4 ячейки стэка, где-то про 128-битное выравнивание регистра-указателя «`rsp`», но откуда появляется этот «Теневой стэк» не понятно

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30190132/9210255

Comment: То есть это просто 4 ячейки стэка нужно сделать свободными и потом вызвать процедуру?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Короче я разобрался. После передачи параметров в процедуру, нужно выделить в стэке 4 ячейки, и ещё сколько-то ячеек чтобы указатель стэка "`rsp`" был выровненным по адресу так, чтобы адрес был кратен 16 (так как есть некоторые SSE-инструкции которые работают только с данными у которых размер 16 байт и некоторые из них без выравнивания не работают). Причём этот адрес должен быть кратным **после** прыжка к адресу функции. То есть чтобы он был выровнен при начале выполнения процедуры. Но для этого нужно чтобы он, перед использованием команды "`call`", был на одну ячейку далёк от выравнивания, так как, **во время** перехода к процедуре командой "`call`", указатель сдвигается на одну ячейку вперёд и таким образом после выполнения этой команды будет уже выровнен, так как сдвинут на одну ячейку вперёд (которой недоставало до выравнивания). То есть нужно выделить свободное место в стэке так, чтобы было **и** место для 4 ячеек стэка **и** указатель стэка "`rsp`" указывал на адрес почти кратный 16 (почти - потому что без одной ячейки). И не забывайте что стэк при старте программы выравнен изначально, поэтому выравнен стэк или нет смотрите сами по своему коду, но смотреть не придётся если вы **всегда** перед вызовом процедуры выравниваете стэк по адресу без-одной-ячейки-кратному 16, ведь каждая процедура будет знать что в её руках всегда выровненный стэк (и вы сами при просмотре кода будете это знать и не придётся считать выравнен указатель или нет).
Вот как это выглядит в коде:

```
mov     rcx, offset nameOfDLL   ; Просто кладём параметр
sub     rsp, 40                 ; Почти выравниваем стэк, без достающей до выравнивания ячейки, попутно выделяя пространство для 4 ячеек (то есть попутно выделяя 32 байта для этих ячеек)
call    LoadLibraryA            ; Вызываем процедуру. Этот вызов передвинет указатель стэка "rsp" на одну ячейку вверх (после сохранения адреса возврата, по которому вернётся вызванная процедура), которой и не доставало до выравнивания. То есть в процедуру указатель "rsp" придёт выровненным
add     rsp, 40                 ; Восстанавливаем стэк обратно. Ведь, в соглашении вызовов в x64, стэк очищается вызвавшим
```

---

С некоторыми процедурами я не встречался и их поведение по отношению к теневому стэку не знаю (я про процедуры, в которых так много входных параметров, что те параметры, которые не вместились в регистры, приходится класть в стэк. Не знаю как они разбираются где их параметры а где начинается теневой стэк). Хотя учитывая что они всегда знают что вызывающий всегда кладёт параметры в стэк начиная с выравненного адреса и заканчивая ближайшим выравниванием, то думаю функции знают как ориентироваться (ещё и зная размер своих параметров)

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то "Теневой стек" - это немного другое..
Система резервирует программам пул памяти для стека определённого размера *(на системах х32 это 256 КБ)*, однако выделяет эту память не всю сразу, а частями по 8 КБ (2 страницы). Выше этих 8 КБ имеется сторожевая страница **"PageGuard"**, и если программа исчерпает стек до сторожевой, то выделяются следующие 8 КБ и т.д. Так вот свободная стековая память и называется "Теневой" *(на рис.ниже это белая часть "свободно")*. Затенённый стек имеется не только на х64, но и на х32.

Раньше были вирусы, которые прятались в теневой памяти стека и ждали, когда система активизирует их страницу. Но с приходом х64 в атрибутах страниц появился бит(NX) и неисполняемый стек, поэтому эти вирусы отжили свой век. Я когда-то проводил опыты со стеком, ознакомиться с которыми можно [здесь](https://codeby.net/threads/stek-obschaja-filosofija.70738/):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эм, Microsoft такого у себя не говорили, поэтому я не так наверно понял. Хотя наверно просто у понятия "Теневой стэк" несколько (как минимум, видимо, два) понятий в разных контекстах. Ну или, как обычно, Microsoft эту информацию запутали у себя в документациях. И, кстати, теперь наверно понятно почему моё указание размера стэка программы не работает (при сборке моей ассемблерной программы) - потому что Windows не выделяет её фиксированно и сразу, а, видимо, как ты сказал(-а), выделяет её динамически (то есть чем больше программа во время работы занимает его, то тем больше стэка выделяется)

Comment: Впрочем, я стэком не пользуюсь. Жалко тратить лишние такты на сдвиг указателей стэков, проще работу своих функций на временных глобальных участках памяти сделать. Заодно и есть гарантия что этот участок памяти есть в кэше одной его линией и никуда не денется нечаянно